/goal_pose topic in navigation2 doesn't work in ros2 humble
I have successfully installed ros2 desktop and turtlebot3 packages in my workspace (ubuntu 22.04). Now I've launched turtlebot3_gazebo and turtlebot3_navigation once i set goal in rviz /goal_pose topic should be published bt it doesn't, I don't know why but I have also checked /cmd_vel topic its working.
I got two questions

/goal_pose topic is not working?
is there any topic in ros2 to indicate that current goal is reached? like /goal_reached
topic in ros1 noetic
enter code here

kindly help

I just tested using the current public Humble binaries: seems to work fine to me.
You should be using an action client if you want to obtain feedback and result statuses from your action request.

thank you for quick reply,
while I set goal in rviz the /goal_pose topic remains blank in the terminal,
I have downloaded navigation2 package in the official ros2 documentation. will you please share the link that you followed.

And also which service(name) should I use to get feedback and result ?

You don't; its part of the client structure to get that information. There are technically private topics that publish that information for the action server, but they are not topics intended for external subscription / handling.
